# How to cut out a fragment of an image in a contour

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I used `OpenCV` for contouring and obtaining `fragments` of parts of clothing on a person, for further classification using a convolutional neural network, I got stuck at the moment of obtaining fragments of clothing after contouring, I need to get an image exactly along the `contour`

[wear.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRIz7.jpg)

[cutted_wear.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p95T.jpg)

[test.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqUpM.jpg)

[edges.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDVHS.png)

[closed.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwV7o.png)

[image: test_final.jpg]

```
import cv2
import imutils
import numpy as np
from rembg import remove
from PIL import Image
```

```
input_path = 'wear.jpg'
output_path = 'cutted_wear.png'
output = remove(Image.open(input_path))
output.save(output_path)
```

```
image = cv2.imread('cutted_wear.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (9, 9), 0)
cv2.imwrite('test.jpg', gray)

edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 25, 130)
cv2.imwrite('edges.jpg', edges)
```

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (10, 10))
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imwrite('closed.jpg', closed)
```

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(closed.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
total = 0
for c in cnts:
    p = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.00001 * p, True)
    if len(approx) > 0:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [approx], -1, (0, 255, ), 4)
        total +=1
print(total)
cv2.imwrite('test_final.jpg', image)
```

Comment: Attach your images, otherwise your script becomes unreproducible.

Comment: the variable `cnts` in an interesting choice.

Comment: @D.L May I add that `for c in cnts:` is an interesting loop as well

Comment: there is nothing interesting about either of those things. I hope you both know of `imutils.grab_contours`. the author of that infamous blog and infamous library propagates this function he wrote that *does* actually pick the contours list out of the 2- or 3-tuple (depending on opencv version) returned by findContours

Comment: why was this tagged "conv-neural-network"? rembg isn't the issue here, or is it?